# How to get full referrer URL (social networks) in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track posts on Instagram which lead to my site. Is it possible to do with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of UTM Parameters, for example by adding the name of the post or a reference in the utm_campaign or utm_content.

Here’s a link for a test post from social to your website:

```
www.yourwebsite.com?utm_source=instagram&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=post_name&utm_content=post_content
```

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't set up the links to my site: I've got lots of traffic from Instagram, but I even don't know from which bloggers.